# How to use the keyboard's mute button to mute only the speakers, not the headphones?

Tags: windows-7, audio, automation

I have a Microsoft Comfort Curve keyboard (KU-0459). It features a set of buttons for volume control. The interesting one is "mute".

I also have a set of USB speakers (Logitech S-150), and a set of headphones with the usual 3.5 mm green/pink jacks going to my on-board sound card.

I am on Windows 7 Ultimate.

I am able to selectively mute the speakers by going into Control Panel -> Sounds -> Playback tab -> Right click speakers -> Disable. I'm very lazy, and I want all of this "clicking" to be done automatically whenever I press my Keyboard's mute button.

If your answer is "AutoHotkey", it would be very nice if you could supply the .ahk script itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written many AutoHotkey scripts to navigate the Control Panel, so I've got you covered! The following script requires that `Show Disabled Devices` is **on**

[image: show disabled devices]

and that **Speakers** is **Enabled** when starting the script.

> Note: in my case, **Speakers** was the 2nd item in the list, so I set the variable `speakers` to `2`.

[image: speakers]

---

```
enabled = 0
speakers = 2

Volume_Mute::
{
    enabled := !enabled

    Run, control /name Microsoft.Sound
    WinWaitActive, Sound

    Send, {Down %speakers%} ;Speakers
    Send, +{F10} ;Right click

    if (enabled = 1)
    {
        Send, d ;Disable
    }
    else
    {
        Send, e ;Enable
    }

    WinClose, Sound

    return
}
```

---

If you are unfamiliar with AutoHotkey or would like a precompiled version of the script, I can provide one that takes the `speaker` variabled as a parameter. Just let me know. :)

Comment: Thank you for the script! It does work if mapped to another key, say, `^m`. However, it doesn't seem to respond to Volume_Mute. Nor does the AHK recorder appear to capture it, for that matter.

Comment: In that case, you can try to find the scan code for your Mute key. See my answer here for instructions: http://superuser.com/a/371141/100787 (Setup; steps 4-10)

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else- with the keyboard model I have, the mute key is SC120, you would use it by replacing `Volume_Mute::` above with `SC120::`.

Comment: Would a variant of this script use to just mute the mic? I have use cases often where I would love a quick way to make sure my mic is disabled without having to fool around with program specific ways (e.g. zoom, Webex etc.)