# AutoHotkey media button for the NextSong button on Pandora

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, autohotkey, media-keys, pandora

I tried doing the same thing that had been advised to do on the [Play/pause pandora.com with a media key](https://superuser.com/questions/368633/play-pause-pandora-com-with-a-media-key) answer page. I simply replaced the *XXX* with *119* after running GetMediaKey - instead of *122* (it was same for me), which worked just fine for its **play/pause** purpose.  I also replaced the *YY* with *11* since it was the appropriate (and next) tab.

It does put the small, orange, dotted square around the next song button, *but instead of going to the next song, it just*  *acts like* ***play/pause***.   Is there another modification required?

Using Google Chrome in Windows 7 on an Alienware m14x r2.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but my solution looks like this

```
SC119::
SetTitleMatchMode, 1
WinGet, original, ID, A
WinActivate, Pandora
Send ^l
Send {Tab 10}
Send {Enter}
WinActivate, ahk_id %original%                                                                                                                       
Exit
```